# Wordpress - Get tag id by slug

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to get id\name of tag by it slug.

Thats my code:

```
$tag = get_term_by('slug', 'hedoms', 'post_tag');
$tag_id =  $tag->term_id;

<h1><?php echo $tag->name;?></h1>
```

I took it from here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

I have tag with the slug **hedoms** but the `<h1>` is empty, it not returns the value. I have tried this function (get_term_by) with category - and same result.

[image]

the 2nd field is the slug.

But if i do it with id and not slug, it works fine:

```
$tag_id = get_term_by('id', 97, 'post_tag');
echo $tag_id->name;
```

It look like the get_term_by recognize only 'id' as field.

What i miss here? it should be on loop or something ?

The file i trying to do it is `archive-product.php` of Woocommerce.

Comment: What about change the "slug" by "name" ?

Comment: @RyanAW I need the slug because i working with ajax filter with tags, so after choosing something from dropdown list it change the url of the page with the slug on query string... and thats why i am using slug. anyway, also with "name" it not works for me. only with id.

Comment: I am sorry for that , is it possible to use rest api ? like `http://yourwebsite/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?slug=hedoms`

Answer (score 9):

```
$tag = get_term_by('slug', ' hedoms','post_tag');

$tag_id =  $tag->term_id;
```

Comment: thanks but... Its the same code of mine. not working.

Comment: @Oshrib have you tried the same in same other file!

Comment: Yep. also on single.php

Comment: Try to `var_dump($tag) ;`

Comment: bool(false) for $tag, NULL for $tag->name;

Comment: But if i change the get_term_by to get it by id, and set the id of the same slug (hedoms) i get the value.
$tag = get_term_by('id', 97, 'post_tag');

Comment: It look like the get_term_by recognize only 'id' as field.

Comment: No as we can pass 'id',  'name',  'slug'.  Check your slug again.

Comment: I have added image print-screen to the question, of the slug from the wp-admin tags section.

Comment: Have tried with wp_query.  `$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Adverts', 'tax_query' => array( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'hedoms', ) ), ) );`

Comment: Than in loop you will get the data which you want.  I.e. `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
/*var_dump()  data*/
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();`

Answer (score 4):

OK i have found the solution.

I set on the get_term_by the taxonomy 'post_tag' instead 'product_tag' as it woocommerce tags. Next time i will look carefully on the url of the wp-admin when i am looking on taxonomy page:

```
...wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_tag&post_type=product
```

So the code should be like that:

```
           $tag = get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'product_tag');
           $tag_name = $tag->name;

           <h1><?php echo $tag_name; ?></h1>
```

Solved.